# Multiple object sets per type are not supported?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

When I create the Scaffold for Controller and add the Model class then I am getting these error "**Multiple object sets per type are not supported**".

I have three Model class :

1.Department.CS

2.Designation.cs

3.CompanyDBContext.cs

Database : I have two table in database, 1. Department(deptID,deptName,Description) 2. Designation(desgtID,desgName,description)

Objective :- I want to create one view page for these scenario. Like this

Insert Name of Form (TextBox) + Department Name (Dropdown list box) + Designation Name (Dropdown list box)

1.Department.CS

```
namespace mvcAppraisalSystem.Models
{
  public class Department
  {
        [Key]
        public int deptID { get; set; }
        public string deptName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

  }
}
```

2.Designation.cs

```
 namespace mvcAppraisalSystem.Models
{
   public class Designation
  {
    [Key]
    public int desgID { get; set; }
    public string desgName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
  }
}
```

3.CompanyDBContext.cs

```
  namespace mvcAppraisalSystem.Models
 {
    public class CompanyDBContext : DbContext
   {
       public CompanyDBContext() : base("CompanyDBContext")
       {


       }
       public DbSet<CompanyDBContext> Departments { get; set; }

       public DbSet<CompanyDBContext> Designations { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're creating your sets to be `DbSet<CompanyDBContext>`. What you want is `DbSet<Department>` and `DbSet<Designation>`.

```
   public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

   public DbSet<Designation> Designations { get; set; }
```

This seems pretty clearly to be a typo, but the reason you're getting the error is because the runtime wouldn't know how to populate multiple object sets on the same context that have the same element type. This would be more like saying:

```
public DbSet<Department> SomeDepartments { get; set; }
public DbSet<Department> OtherDepartments { get; set; }
```

Since (presumably) you would expect something to define what would be in `SomeDepartments` and there would be something to define what's in `OtherDepartments` and the runtime doesn't know this (and there's no way to express it), that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: ok, I got your point. my aim is, I want to create one view page for both model class. like i said im my que?

Comment: You're asking two different questions. The error you posted is because of the problem I've pointed out in this answer.

Comment: Yes, you are completely wright. Thanks for your help but I want your help for my full question which I mentioned in Objective of my question.

Comment: If you have a second question, please post it as a separate question. Since SO is intended to be a Q&A site that's easily searchable, combining questions is generally not allowed (since it makes it more difficult to find questions that relate to what someone is looking for). Since the title of your question and the bulk of its body relates to this error, you can feel free to leave this question as-is (and mark this answer as accepted if it solved that issue for you), then post another question for your additional problem.